# why SaveSvgAsPng don't support tag <br>

Tags: javascript, html

When I create an image with savevgaspng without the br / tag everything is fine, but if I include it inside to create a new line inside a

is where it fails

Comment: Post an example of your SVG code. AFAIK `<br>` is not a valid SVG tag.

Comment: How can I create a line break? if not with <br>

Comment: There is no built in way to create a new line inside of SVG text. The only way is to manually create a second text element with a position below that of the line preceding it. That will require you to do some manual calculation to figure out the text height and position relative to other text elements.